# How to assert the expect number of result rows of a sub-query in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Often times I find myself writing code such as:

```
const fooId = await pool.oneFirst(sql`
  SELECT id
  FROM foo
  WHERE nid = 'BAR'
`);

await pool.query(sql`
  INSERT INTO bar (foo_id)
  VALUES (${fooId})
`);
```

`oneFirst` is a [Slonik](https://github.com/gajus/slonik) query method that ensures that the query returns exactly 1 result. It is needed there, because `foo_id` also accepts `NULL` as a valid value, i.e. if `SELECT id FROM foo WHERE status = 'BAR'` returned no results, this part of the program would fail silently.

The problem with this approach is that it causes two database roundtrips for what should be a single operation.

In a perfect world, [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) supported assertions natively, e.g.

```sql
INSERT INTO bar (foo_id)
VALUES
(
  (
    SELECT id
    FROM foo
    WHERE nid = 'BAR'
    EXPECT 1 RESULT
  )
)
```

> `EXPECT 1 RESULT` is a made up DSL.

The expectation is that `EXPECT 1 RESULT` would cause PostgreSQL to throw an error if that query returns anything other than 1 result.

Since PostgreSQL does not support this natively, what are the client-side solutions?

Comment: This is an inconsistent problem description, none of your queries match on table, fields, etc. Create a consistent question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver re-read the question? I've not made mistakes in these queries as far as I can tell.

Comment: `SELECT id FROM foo WHERE status = 'BAR'` then `SELECT id FROM foo WHERE nid = 'BAR'`.  `INSERT INTO bar (foo_id)  VALUES (${fooId})` then  `INSERT INTO (foo_id)
VALUES ...`

Comment: Corrected. Thanks

Comment: Still thinking it is `INSERT INTO bar (foo_id) VALUES (  ( SELECT id ...`. In any case a quick and dirty solution would be to do `SELECT COALESCE(id, 1/0) FROM foo WHERE nid = 'BAR' ...` for the `NULL` case. Still working on the >1 case. Though why do you want only one results and why would `LIMIT 1` not work?

Comment: If `SELECT id FROM foo WHERE nid = 'BAR'` returned more than 1 result, then it would indicate either a mistake in schema or that the expectations have changed since the time the code was written. In either case, it should throw an error.

Comment: Then why not put a PK or UNIQUE index on `nid`?

Comment: This is a very obvious case, it won't be as explicit like this all the time. In any case, that's the idea – there should be a unique constraint on that value, but if query is modified or if database schema changed, you wouldn't want your application to blindly rely on it – thus the need/want to assert the expected output.

Comment: Right off the top I'm going to say asserting on production data is going down the rabbit hole. The safer thing to do is have a schema management/migration process that includes tests on schema changes.  Then you catch the mistakes before they get into the live data. Personally I use [Sqitch](https://sqitch.org/) for schema management and [pgTAP](https://pgtap.org/) for testing. FYI, both where created by the same person.

Answer (score 3):

That's a cool idea.

You can cause an error on extra results by putting the select in a context where only one result is expected. For example, just writing

`SELECT (SELECT id from foo WHERE nid = 'bar')`

will get you a decent error message on multiple results: `error: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`.

To handle the case where nothing is returned, you could use COALESCE.

Comment: I like this! I wish PostgreSQL had something explicit, as it may be hard to understand the intent behind this, but it does get the job done.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
const fooId = await pool.oneFirst(sql`
  INSERT INTO bar (foo_id)
  SELECT id
  FROM foo
  WHERE nid = 'BAR'
  RETURNING foo_id;
`);
```

This will insert all rows matched by the condition in `foo` into `bar`, and Slonik will throw if that was not exactly one row.

Alternatively, if you insist on using `VALUES` with a subquery, you can do

```
INSERT INTO bar (foo_id)
SELECT tmp.id
FROM (VALUES (
  SELECT id
  FROM foo
  WHERE nid = 'BAR'
)) AS tmp
WHERE tmp.id IS NOT NULL
```

Nothing would be inserted if no row did match the condition and your application could check that. Postgres would throw an exception if multiple rows were matched, since a subquery in an expression must return at most one row.